# ExecutorService: the output is not expected

Tags: java, runnable, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I have difficulty in understanding the output. Here I create an executor, and then submit a `Runnable` task to it 1000 times. The expected output is 1000, since I have add `synchronized` inside of `Runable`, but the real output is not, e.g., 503. Can anyone help explain it for me? bv

```
public class FutureTest {

    int count=0;

    public void testExecutor(){
        CountDownLatch counter = new CountDownLatch(1000);
        Runnable incr = ()->{
            //System.out.println("count="+count);
            synchronized(this){
                count++;    
            }
            counter.countDown();

        };
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        IntStream.range(0, 1000).forEach(i->service.submit(incr));
        counter.await();
        service.shutdown();

        System.out.println(count);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FutureTest().testExecutor();

    }

}
```

Comment: You're printing out the count before all threads are completed. You need a countdown latch

Comment: Just add a `Thread.sleep(10)` within the Runnable to see what I mean. The count then is 0

Comment: @NathanHughes, here `this` is `new FutureTest()` that was created in the main method.

Comment: @NathanHughes: print out the `hashCode()` from the `this` used for synchronization -- they're all the same object, so his synchronization lock is in fact correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing out the count in the calling thread, and before all the Runnable code in the calculating threads has been called. Just put a short Thread.sleep within your Runnable to see the count be even less.

```
public void testExecutor(){
    Runnable incr = ()->{
        //System.out.println("count="+count);
        synchronized(this){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            catch (InterruptedException e){}
            count++;    
        }
    };
```

You'll want to use some notification for when all threads have completed their actions, such as a count down latch or `.awaitTermination(...)`.

```
    IntStream.range(0, 1000).forEach(i->service.submit(incr));
    service.shutdown();

    try {
        service.awaitTermination(1000, TimerUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e){}

    System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Thanks. I add `CountDownLatch` and then it is OK now.